# Self hosted game server security

Tags: security, ip, port, gaming, self-hosting

Not sure if this is the correct place to post this question...

My son keeps asking to set up a minecraft server on his PC which then gives him control over the "world" and he can invite people to play on his server...

In order for people to log onto his self-hosted version, they need to enter the public IP followed by a port number

My question is:
If he gives the Public IP to the wrong person, would this put our home network at risk of being hacked?
I run my business from home and would rather make sure that there was no risk posed if I do allow him to set up a self hosted server

Comment: Do worry all public IPv4 addresses are regularly scanned for all (common) open ports by various people. So it doesn't matter to whom you give the IP. Just make sure the server uses strong authentication (good passwords) so only invited people can enter.

Comment: @Robert - A Minecraft server doesn't really use a password, unless you configure one, but that is not a security feature necessarily.  It's to only allow players you want to join your world.  The solution to this problem is to use a separate VLAN for the Minecraft server, and make it so that it cannot communicate, with any device you want to isolate.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right place to ask this kind of question, and you are right, there are risks involved giving personal information like IP-Addresses (if you have a static one) to people you don't know. But those are manageable. As King Six already pointed out, nowadays bots scan almost all known IPv4 addresses all the time hoping to find a hole in the firewall in order to gain profit from exploiting the connected network. If you have a router that is not from the last decade, it will probably handle all "attacks" going to other ports than the one your Mineraft Server is listening on. Only the connections that go directly through the router to the device running the server need to be handled by the firewall on the server side.

Though instead of having the server run on your son's computer, so that it needs to be powered on all the time, I would consider installing it to different hardware like a Raspberry PI 4 or something similar, so that

1. you have full control over it. Your son probably doesn't know how to manage a server himself, otherwise he would do it. If you have full control, you can install additional things like another firewall for security improvement.
2. it runs Linux. Having a Linux machine be the server makes it extremely easy to install and manage as there are not only dozens of tutorials online, but also complete (and trusted) [scripts like this one](https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-minecraft-server-script-with-startup-service/) that automate the installation as well as managing (i.e. starting, stopping and updateing) the server.
3. you can leave it running 24/7. A small Linux server like the Raspberry PI consumes way less energy than a normal laptop/PC that your son is probably using, so it is better for your wallet as well as for the environment, if you want to think about that.

Last but not least I would recommend to keep an eye on recent developments concerning the zero day exploit Log4Shell as it is very very easy to get access to the hardware running the server as well as the connected network, if you do not patch all related security problems.

Comment: That takes care of the hardware, but to isolate it from your office network run it on a guest wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no open ports on your network except the port needed for your Minecraft server and you should be fine. If you are worried you can use a tunneling tool, like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), that will provide tunnel to localhost without exposing your real IP.